# How to retrive a Control in a specific ROW in edit mode in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with many rows.

When a User click the **EDIT button** in GridView I need to retrieve a Control in that specific row (now in edit mode).
This Logic should work on GridEvent `_RowUpdating`

At the moment my code (wrong) look inside every Row, so the Control founded is not unique and I receive an error.

```
// Event handler
    protected void uxManageSponsoredContentsDisplayer_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
```

---

```
// My code (Wrong!!!!):
foreach (GridViewRow row in uxManageSponsoredContentsDisplayer.Rows)
    {
    TextBox uxStartDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("uxEffectiveStartDateInput");
    }
```

Hope my question is clear. Any idea how to do it? Thanks

---

Solution:

```
    TextBox uxStartDate = (TextBox)uxManageSponsoredContentsDisplayer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("uxEffectiveStartDateInput");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs e` as it contains index of row being updated.

Use something like

```
uxManageSponsoredContentsDisplayer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("uxEffectiveStartDateInput")
```